# Conflict between "\left \right" brackets and "align"

Tags: align, brackets

In the following example, I would like to align the two equations where there are the symbols of "integral", but I get an error if I place the "&" sign (of the "align" environment) between the "\left( \right)" brackets. **Any solution?**

The following works (the "&" sign is outside the "\left( \right)" brackets):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
I = \inf_{x} &\int f(x)dx \\
  = &\left( \int_{\Omega} f(u)du \right)  \\ \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**The following is what I would like to achieve, but it does not work** (the "&" sign is between the "\left( \right)" brackets):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
I = \inf_{x} &\int f(x)dx \\
  = \left( &\int_{\Omega} f(u)du \right)  \\ \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The error is the following:

> This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:
> There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
> The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
> This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

Comment: You cannot have a line break or `&` inside a `\left ... \right` pair. The parser cannot see it. Instead manually scale the fences using one of `\big\Big\bigg\Bigg` (I normally use the `\xxxl` and `\xxxr` variants, as in `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`)'

Comment: Many thanks, with the ```\big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg(``` commands it works!! However, I do not know about the ```\xxxl``` and ```\xxxr``` variants...never seen them so far.. :-)

Comment: They are used in certain cases there it matters whether the fence should be marked as open (l) or close (r). Consider `|-2 < x < 2` compare with `\bigl|-2<x<2`, the spacing is different. `|` is a normal symbol, and unless I'm mistaken so is `\big(` but `\bigl(` marks it as an _open_. The `|` if used in say `\{... | ... \}` can be helped using `|\mathopen{}` that also tells `-` that it comes after an _open_ and thus is a sign, not addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation @daleif! :-)